# What can cause memory leaks other than using new? (c++)

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

What can cause memory leaks in C++ other than using the new keyword to assign memory? I have a project and there seem to be several memory leaks all over the show but I haven't used the new keyword once. Also when I accidentally left it running for a number of hours(4-6) I came back to see it had been slowly swallowing up cpu cycles too.. not sure if this would of been a direct result of the memory leaks(by this point it was using pretty much all of my available memory) as it's not obviously happening when starting the program again, but the memory leaks are.
Thanks!

Comment: You might not directly call `new` yourself but functions that you call from another party might. We can't know without code.

Comment: For memory leaks debugging you can use Valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

It could be various things like

- An ever-growing list, like adding to a `vector` and never removing
- Forgetting to close open resources like file handles, sockets, etc.
- A memory leak in a third party library
- Circular references if you are reference counting

Answer (score 1):

- Using `malloc`, `realloc` or `calloc` or platform specific allocation functions like `mmap` and losing the returned pointer.
- Using a function (possibly a constructor) that itself allocates memory, but not calling the correspoding release function. For example, calling `SDL_Init` without calling `SDL_Quit`.
- Using third party code that leaks memory even if used correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to chew CPU and memory.

Profiling is the best tool to see what's using the CPU. If you have some logging you should be able to tell where it is spending time.

Strings are culprits for memory use surprisingly often - if you read a large amount of data near the start of the program (e.g. XML config etc) and don't let this go out of scope it will hang around til the program ends, even if you didn't explicitly call `new` yourself. Keeping handles open, e.g. database connections, files etc will also eat resources.

You can also easily end up copying data around if you don't use references or other ways to share.

Try to find a simple way to measure what you are doing and take it from there.